# Template class with no use of template argument

Tags: c++, templates, software-design

I have stumbled many times on classes defined like

```
class PureVirtualClass
{
   virtual int foo() = 0;
   virtual bool bar() = 0;
}

template <class T> class ImplClass : public virtual PureVirtualClass
{
   virtual ~ImplClass(){};
   int foo()  { return 42;}
   bool bar() { return true;}
   //several other method having nothing to do with T
}
```

This "design" appears so often I want to think the original developer knew what he was doing by defining `ImplClass` as template class but without *any reference* to the template argument `T` *anywhere*. My own c++ template knowledge is kinda limited.

Is there a benefit to this or is it just a confused programmer?

Comment: maybe he's too lazy to split the classes into .h and .cpp files?

Comment: @Philipp he could still provide all of the definition in the header without the class being a template.

Comment: Possible base class for CRTP?

Comment: It is a *bad* ways to have several identical classes...

Comment: It allows you to trivially generate different types, which may be needed for client code. It also allows you to specialize for certain types `T`.

Comment: Mixing static polymorphism (templates) and dynamic polymorphism (virtual) might be code-smell

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks. Can you develop a bit in an answer please?

Comment: @DieterLücking depends. While you can produce smelly code with it, combining the benefits of both static and dynamic polymorphism has some very powerful applications in modern C++.

Comment: @Philipp: Never thought of *that* :D

Comment: "Many times"? With so much `virtual` stuff inside? From the same programmer or different ones? More detail would be nice. Certainly unused parameters are useful for metaprogramming, but meta-stuff tends to contain nothing inside that operates at runtime.

Comment: @ArneMertz: but without using templates, this would result in linker errors if the classes are used in multiple compilations units, whereas the linker handles this problem with templates for you. (Don't get me wrong, I wouldn't recommend this :-))

Comment: @Philipp: You are onto something :). the classes are used in several compilation unit. because your idea is different, why don't you post an answer? I will gladly upvote.

Comment: @Philipp amything you define inside the class does not violate ODR (functions are implicitly `inline`). So only things you (have to) define outside can cause such errors, and since you can add explicit `inline` declarations to functions, the only thing that is only solvable through templating the class are static data members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *can* be a benefit for classes being templated but not depending on the argument. Most often you see such things to define (empty) tag-structures for template metaprogramming:

```
template <class X>
struct some_tag {};
```

---

The benefit of classes like yours in general is that while you have the same functionality in each class, they are different classes and you can't copy one into the other, i.e. an object of type `ImplClass<int>` is not compatible with another object of type `ImplCalss<float>`.

Comment: Yeah, but a full-blown class with virtual bases and virtual functions is something else.

Answer (score 3):

There are many useful cases of the idea mentioned by [Arne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23105272/2644390). For instance, looking at [Very basic tuple implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44832/39083), this is how a single tuple element is defined:

```
template <size_t N, typename T>
class TupleElem
{
    T elem;
public:
    T&       get()       { return elem; }
    const T& get() const { return elem; }
};
```

It is templated on `N`, without depending on it. Why? Because the tuple implementation

```
template <size_t... N, typename... T>
class TupleImpl <sizes <N...>, T...> : TupleElem <N, T>...
{
    //..
};
```

derives multiple such elements, each with a unique `N`, serving as an *identifier*. Without it, `TupleImpl` would be deriving the same class twice, had two element types been identical within parameter pack `T...`. Neither [random access](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) to elements would work in this case (via an explicit call of function `get()` of the appropriate `TupleElem` base class, which would be ambiguous), nor [empty base optimization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization) (via specializing `TupleElem` for empty types `T` to *not* have a data member of type `T`).

This is a real use case, and exactly how `std::tuple` is implemented by clang. Of course, a class like `TupleElem` would be a hidden implementation detail, and not part of the interface. For instance, gcc follows an entirely different recursive class design.

In general, you will need to study the *context* where classes are used to understand the intent of the designer.

Answer (score 1):

maybe that developer simply is too lazy to split the classes into .h and .cpp files?

Without using templates, linker errors would occur if the classes are used in multiple compilations units. When using templates, the linker usually discards duplicate instantiations of a template at link time (or handles the problem in a different way).

While this may be an answer to "why did the developer do this", I would not recommend this if the question was "when should I introduce template arguments which are never used" (see the other answers for this). Even though it is annoying to split code into .h and .cpp (especially when used to languages like Java or C#), it's the usual C++ way. And it is definitely easier to read/understand than using templates only for this purpose. Also, it makes the *use* of the classes less readable.

Comment: As I explained in the comments above, this is only a explanation if the classes contain static data members, which is not evident in the example code. On the other hand, since that kind of laziness would be a very stupid reason for using templates, a developer who considers it might not even know tha inlining the method definitions would be sufficient. ;-)